# Change action bar style and color for Google Play Games Leaderboard, Achievements, etc.?

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using Google Play Games APIs for my app.  When I use the following to launch the Achievements display for my app:

```
startActivityForResult(
                    getGamesClient().getAchievementsIntent(), 2);
```

The activity that launches has a different action bar color than what I'm using in my main app.

How can I customize this action bar color to match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't customize that screen. It's important for that screen to look like Google Play Games and not a specific game because that gives the user a feeling of familiarity -- that screen is the same across several of the games they play.

If you want to have a completely customized and immersive experience, you can use the raw data APIs. For example, call [GamesClient.loadAchievements()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#loadAchievements%28com.google.android.gms.games.achievement.OnAchievementsLoadedListener,%20boolean%29) to load the achievements and display them in a custom UI.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, this makes sense.  Which method would I use to pull down the leaderboard data that's normally shown in getLeaderboardIntent?

Comment: GamesClient.loadTopScores() and GamesClient.loadPlayerCenteredScores() are the ones you'll want to call. Notice that one of the parameters is the "collection", which can be either "public" or "social" -- this specifies if you want the public scores or the player's social scores.