# How to redefine the default activity that displays player's achievements in Android Play Game Services?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using the Android Play Games services through the Android SDK. The most straightforward way of displaying player's achievements is to call getAchievementsIntent() to get an Intent to create the default achievements UI and bring up the UI by calling startActivityForResult as shown below:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient()), REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
```

This intent includes an intent-filter action (com.google.android.gms.games.VIEW_ACHIEVEMENTS) filtered by a specific Activity included in the play services (com.google.android.gms.games.ui.client.achievements.ClientAchievementListActivity) libraries. As far as I know it's not possible to extend such activity and its source code is not available. How could I redefine some styles in the activity (for instance change the action bar background color)? Is it possible to know which styles is using the Activity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to customize that activity, as it's answered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333612/change-action-bar-style-and-color-for-google-play-games-leaderboard-achievement).

You could design your own Achievements Activity using the [load method at com.google.android.gms.games.achievement.Achievements](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements.html#load(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20boolean)), or you could try to make your game style similar to Google Play Games UI.